# Nextpeer LibGdx Error

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, nextpeer

I am brand new to LibGdx (3 days of experiance on me... so im eh)
And I got Nextpeer about 3 hours ago and I can't to anything without 100 errors. The documentation is leaving out details (I think) and i can't figure out what to do...

I have non of Nextpeer setup code wise, everything is loaded into my Eclipse IDE.

So... What am I asking about?

Well, before I ask, let me tell you my situation.

LibGdx Flow:
Main.java -> MainMenuScreen.java -> (NextPeer Menu?) -> Game.java

I have tried running the NextParse.Init in the main class but I an **error saying I need to configure my build path**. ? what ? Maybe I sound nooby, so there is problem number 1. Alright... So now lets say I did initialize my software somehow... https://nextpeer.atlassian.net/wiki/display/NS/libGDX says to use this constructor

```
public SuperJumper(Tournaments tournaments) {
    // If we have a supported tournaments object, set the game as callback
    if (tournaments != null && tournaments.isSupported()) {
        tournaments.setTournamentsCallback(this);
         
        // Load Nextpeer plugin with the tournaments instance
        NextpeerPlugin.load(tournaments);
    }
```

So I use the constructor but I then get the error on

```
tournaments.setTournamentsCallback(this);
```

IDE Error Warning thing: `The method setTournamentsCallback(TournamentsCallback) in the type Tournaments is not applicable for the arguments (GameScreen)`

Do I know what I am doing... not really w/ NextPeer.

Please attempt to help me w/ the problems above, or explain some concepts to me. Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest using Google Play Game Services instead of NextPeer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the wiki:

> Next, we'll have the Game subclass conform to the
>   TournamentsCallback.java interface.

Let SuperJumper implement TournamentsCallback interface and then the code above should work.

Comment: Thanks, If you could help me out w/ one more thing! :) How do I init the nextpeer in libGdx? (Not android specific)